# Django: How can I make a custom admin view that edits a JSON file, rather than a model?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-admin

My goal is to add an extra view to my admin page that edits a json file, rather than my database. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites) says that custom views can be added by overriding the `get_urls()` method in my custom `AdminSite` class. It goes on to say:

> Any view you render that uses the admin templates, or extends the base admin template, should set `request.current_app` before rendering the template. It should be set to either `self.name` if your view is on an `AdminSite` or `self.admin_site.name` if your view is on a `ModelAdmin`.

As you can see here, I tried doing just that (see the first line of the `json_admin_view()` method):

```
import json

from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
from django.urls import path
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import JsonForm

JSON_FILE = 'json_app/data.json'

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    site_header = "JSON App Administration"

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            path('json_admin/',
                 self.admin_view(self.json_admin_view),
                 name='json_admin')
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def json_admin_view(self, request):
        request.current_app = self.name  # This doesn't seem to do anything

        context = {}

        with open(JSON_FILE, 'r') as read_data:
            json_data = json.load(read_data)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = JsonForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                with open(JSON_FILE, 'w') as write_data:
                    json.dump(form.cleaned_data, write_data)
                    context.update({'form_saved': True})

        else:
            form = JsonForm({
                'fname': json_data['fname'],
                'lname': json_data['lname'],
            })

        context.update({'form': form})

        return render(request, 'json_app/admin/json_admin.html', context)
```

I'm able to visit `/admin/json_admin/`, and it works fine, except the header shows "Django Administration" instead of "JSON App Administration", even though `json_admin.html` extends `admin/base_site.html`. Also, I would like to have a link to the view show up on the admin index page, as if it were a normal modal change form. So I have two questions:

1. How come I'm not seeing "JSON App Administration" on the header of my custom admin page? I assume `request.current_app = self.name` is meant to help with that, but perhaps I'm using it incorrectly.
2. How do I add a link to the custom admin page from the admin index? If it were a model I could just use `register()`, but I can't do that since it's not a model.

If you know a better way of editing a json file from the admin page, I'd be happy to hear that as well.